# How to read a string array in appSettings.json?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, configuration, .net-core

My env is VS Code and .NET Core 2.0.

I need to read a status code and several pairs of code/message from my appsetting.json.

This is my appsettings.json file

```
{
  "http": 
  {
    "statuscode": 200
  },
  "responses": 
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "ok"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "message": "erro"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm loading the configuration file and data like below, but everything is null:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _conf;
const string APPSET_SEC = "responses";
const string APPSET_KEY = "data";

public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _conf = configuration;

    var section = _conf.GetSection($"{APPSET_SEC}:{APPSET_KEY}");
    var responses = section.Get<string[]>();

    var someArray = _conf.GetSection(APPSET_SEC).GetChildren().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Either responses and someArray are null. It appears that the string array is not valid but it looks like a valid Json string array. What do I need to modify my appsettings or my C# code to get "data" array loaded into the variable?

I tried a simplified array in json file

```
{
    "statuscode": 200,
    "data": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "ok"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "message": "erro"
      }
    ]
 }
```

using the code:

```
var section = _conf.GetSection($"{APPSET_SEC}");
var responses = section.Get<string[]>();
```

but I still got no joy

Comment: you are trying to get it as a string array when it is an object array, create a POCO model to match the setting and get an array of that

Answer (score 14):

You are trying to get it as a string array `string[]` when it is an object array,

Create a POCO model to match the setting

```
public class ResponseSeting {
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

and get an array of that.

So given the following *appsetting.json*

```
{
  "http": 
  {
    "statuscode": 200
  },
  "responses": 
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "ok"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "message": "erro"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The response data would be extracted like

```
var responses = Configuration
    .GetSection("responses:data")
    .Get<ResponseSeting[]>();
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be done in java using rest-assured library

JSON.body("http.statuscode") --> Will get the statuscode

```
JSON.body(responses.data.code[0]) --> will get the response code
JSON.body(responses.data.message[0])---> will get the response message
JSON.body(responses.data.code[1])
JSON.body(responses.data.message[1])
```

Ain't got a scoobydo on how VScode works. But long story short, this might help you!!!