# How to bind configuration to array of JSON Objects .Net Core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, configuration

I'm trying to bind a JSON file to a model for configuration settings in a dotnet core project.

The json looks like:

```
"Settings": {
  "Values": [
  { "Value1": "1" },
  { "Value2": "2" }
]}
```

My model looks like:

```
public class Settings
{
    public List<Value> Values{ get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I bind with the following:

```
var settings = _configuration.GetSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
```

But this results in `settings` containing two `Value` objects in the list - the first `Value` object has `Value1 = 1` & `Value2 = null`, and the second `Value` object has `Value1 = null` & `Value2 = 2`. How can I bind such that it `settings` only has one `Value` object in `Values` with both properties populated?

This is not the same as suggested here:
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488845/how-to-read-a-string-array-in-appsettings-json](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488845/how-to-read-a-string-array-in-appsettings-json)

This is because each object in the array in this case have different properties whereas in the proposed duplicate all objects are consistent.

Comment: If you want only one Value object, define only one Value object: `"Values": [ { "Value1": "1", "Value2": "2" } ]`

Comment: @EdPlunkett in the Json file?

Comment: Yes. What you're getting now is exactly what the current JSON describes.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Is there any other way to achieve this without changing the JSON?

Comment: You could write some weird code to condense/coalesce/whatever the list into a single object, I guess. You can write code to do just about anything. How did it get this way? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Oh well, Thanks for the help! ;) - It was part of a task I was given for an interview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a string array in appSettings.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488845/how-to-read-a-string-array-in-appsettings-json)

Comment: not quite the same - the objects in the arrays from the link you posted all have the same properties so the proposed solution does not work in this case.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all! this Question here is about a specific parsing issue of an array

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get your values is probably to make your Class look like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] Values{ get; set; }
}
```

This will be parsed as an `Array` of `Dictionary` items, where each item will contain only 1 key-value of your Values.

**UPDATE:**

You can add a function inside your `Settings` class to get all the settings as 1 dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetSettings()
{
    var settingsValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var valueDict in Values)
    {
        foreach (var setting in valueDict)
        {
            settingsValues.Add(setting.Key, setting.Value);
        }
    }
    return settingsValues;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that going to want curly braces around the contents of "Values", not square brackets?

Comment: It's a dictionary, which will be an array of key-value objects, so it would be exactly as this JSON mentioned in the Question.

Comment: I was testing with Newtonsoft. How should I test?

Comment: This throws `{System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.`

Comment: @MayerSpitzer and Ed Plunkett - Got it! Thanks again for the help

Comment: I'd suggest deleting our comments since it is not so relevant after making edits

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it actually needs to look like:

```
public class Settings
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Values{ get; set; }
}
```

Since the JSON `Values` is actually an array of dictionaries.

For the following to work:

```
public class Settings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values{ get; set; }
}
```

The JSON would need to look like:

```
"Settings": {
    "Values": {    
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "2"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but I have no idea why, since in JSON it is simply an array of `KeyValuePair`

Comment: But that's the same isn't it - an array of `KeyValuePair` is an array of dictionaries? But it was not easy to spot - I tried the dictionary earlier today but missed that it was an array of them

Comment: A dictionary is an array itself, it's a collection of `KeyValuePair`

Comment: true, I guess the JSON here is an array of JSON objects - those objects being `KeyValuePairs` can be represented with a dictionary in C# - but it is still an array of said objects